# Pentaho combining keys of 3 tables

Tags: mysql, pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I have 3 tables.
The tables are of hierarchial nature.

For instance:

Table 1 : Contains state information 
Table2  : City Information
Table 3 : Locality Information

The Key in Table1 is set as 1,2,3, and there is a foreign key constrain on Table2 and the PK of table2 is the foreign key of Table3.

The Key of Table 2 should be set as 1.1 1.2 and so on.
The key of Table 3 should be set as 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 and so forth.

```
Table 1 :     1 , Karnataka
Table 2 :     1.1,Bangalore
              1.2,Mysore
Table3   :    1.1.1 OMR
              1.1.2 MGRoad
              1.2.1 MysoreLocality1
```

Is there any steps / combination of steps that we can use to achieve this using Pentaho Data Integration?

I tried a combination of `Merge/Join` and `Add Constants`, `Sequence generator` in vain.

Comment: Could you describe an input for Pentaho Data Integration and desired output?

Comment: Input would be 3 tables. Output would be an added column in the last 2 tables.

Comment: @rasikavijay is the key values of Table 2 is 1.1, 1.2, ..._(i mean it is already present in that format in the db table)_ ?? or it should be set/updated ??... got confused with the line `"The Key of Table 2 should be set as 1.1 1.2 and so on."`...